Weighted squared norm of multivariate truncated normal vector
Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$ be a multivariate normal vector with zero mean and inverse covariance matrix
$$
    \Sigma^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
        n & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1& 1 \\
        1 & n-1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n},
$$
i.e., $\Sigma^{-1}$ is the sum of a diagonal matrix $D = \mathrm{diag}(n, n-1, \cdots, 2, 1)$
and an upper-left triangular matrix of ones, except with zeroes on the diagonal.
Question: I am interested in bounding from above the squared norm of $X$ weighted by the diagonal values
of $\Sigma^{-1}$, conditional on $X > 0$ (with the inequality taken element-wise):
$$
    \mathbb{E}\left[
        \sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma_{ii}^{-1} X_i^2 \mid X \geq 0
    \right].
$$
Equivalently, we can consider $X$ as a multivariate normal vector truncated from below.
In particular, I want to find an upper bound of the form
$$
    \mathbb{E}\left[
        \sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma_{ii}^{-1} X_i^2 \mid X \geq 0
    \right] \overset{?}{\leq} \epsilon n,
$$
where $\epsilon < 1$ is a constant. Numerical experimentation shows that $\epsilon < 0.7$,
however, any constant strictly smaller than $1$ suits my needs.
Bonus Question: a better bound could be obtained by taking $X \in [0, 1]^n$ rather
than $X \geq 0$. In this case, numerical experiments give $\epsilon < 0.6$. This problems seems intuitively harder to me, but I am including
it here in case it turns out to be easier to find a nontrivial bound this way.

Manjunath and Wilhelm [1] provide explicit formulas for all moments of the truncated
multivariate normal in terms of $\Sigma$, as well as a table of previous results.
These formulas would allow us to compute the expectations above in principle. Unfortunately
they are quite cumbersome and involve marginal probability densities of subsets of the variables,
which we do not have direct access to.
My hope is that the structure of the problem allows a much simpler computation
to obtain an upper bound on $\epsilon$. In fact, a compact calculation yielding a crude upper bound is much
preferred over an involved exact one.
[1] Manjunath, B. G., & Wilhelm, S. (2021). Moments Calculation for the Doubly Truncated Multivariate Normal Density. Journal of Behavioral Data Science, 1(1), 17-33. https://doi.org/10.35566/jbds/v1n1/p2
